# IF THEN Statement Multiple Conditions

Tags: excel

I'm trying to design an excel formula for some golf game scores.  Golfers get points based on a random number (0-9) and the last digit of their score.  So, if the random number is 0 and the golfers score ends in 0, they get 10 points.  Still with a 0 random number, if the golfers score ends in a 1, they get 9 points. 8 points for a last digit of 2.  7 for 3. 6 for 4.  10 for 5.  9 for 6.  8 for 7.  7 for 8.  6 for 9.

```
Score ends in:    Points:
0                 10
1                  9
2                  8
3                  7
4                  6
5                 10
6                  9
7                  8
8                  7
9                  6
```

As long as I come up with one formula for the random number of 0, I can adjust it for the remaining 9 random numbers.

The way I was hoping for this to work was to just be able to enter the scores into one column and then have the points calculated in a separate column.  There will also have to be a cell where I enter the random number.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this to get the score if the random number is `0`:

```
=IF(A1=0,10-MOD(RIGHT(B1),5))
```

This will give the points you mentioned provided:

`A1` is the cell containing the random number

`B1` is the cell containing the points of the golfer.

The main formula here is:

```
10-MOD(RIGHT(B1),5)
```

`RIGHT()` takes the last digit of the points. `MOD(,5)` will get the remainder when this digit is divided by 5.

When you have 0, you get no remainder, hence 0.

When you have 1, you get a remainder of 1, hence 1.

When you have 2, you get a remainder of 2, hence 2.

When you have 6, you get a remainder of 1, hence 1 again.

Then 10 minus that remainder gives you the points you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You could certainly use `=RAND()*10`to get a random value in excel. Or to get a value without commas use `= ROUNDDOWN(RAND()*10;0)`

Then you add something a `VLOOKUP`to get a value to each players score. `RIGHT(A1;1)`gives you the last value of a field.

`VLOOKUP`requires you to have a table somewhere with the values for each score as you described.

edit: the MOD solution looks even better. Please note that RANDOM gets a fresh value everytime you refresh the XLS sheet. so probably use it to get a value and put that into another field manually.